# How can I update a property of mainWindowViewModel from another ViewModel?

Tags: wpf, mvvm

From mainWIndow.xaml, which uses as DataContext the mainWindowViewModel, I opening a new window with name addNewItem.xaml, which uses as DataContext the ItemsViewModel.

In addNewItem.xaml I have a DataGrid

```
<DataGrid SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedHotel}" ItemsSource="{Binding HotelsList}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="350" Header="Hotel" IsReadOnly="True">
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Label Content="{Binding Path=Name}"></Label>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
               </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
```

I want to pass the **SelectedHotel** from ItemsViewModel to mainWindowViewModel.

I tried to do this with the following code (with no luck)

```
    //This is a property from ItemsViewModel
    private Hotel _selectedHotel { get; set; }
    public Hotel SelectedHotel {
        get { return _selectedHotel; }
        set {
            _selectedHotel = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedHotel");
            OnSelectedItemChanged();
        }
    }
   void OnSelectedItemChanged() {
        MainWIndowViewModel = new MainWIndowViewModel(this.SelectedHotel);
    }
```

In mainWIndowViewModel I have also one more Property (with same name, SelectedHotel) which it gets value through the constructor

```
 public MainWIndowViewModel(Hotel selectedHotel)
        : this(new ModalDialogService()) {
        this.SelectedHotel = selectedHotel;
    }
```

In mainWindow.xaml I want to display a value of the property

```
<Label Content="{Binding SelectedHotel.Name}" DockPanel.Dock="Top"></Label>
```

what am I doing wrong?

In general, I need to know the rule of doing something like this.

How could I notify a property from another property?

Thanks

**Solution**

I solve it with messages from mvvm light.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found a solution and this comes from mediator pattern. I use the mvvmLight.

From mainWindowViewModel, I registered a *message* (I don't know if the term of message is the correct one)

```
 public MainWIndowViewModel(IDialogService dialog) {
        this._dialog = dialog;
        Messenger.Default.Register<NotificationMessage<Hotel>>(this, NotificationMessageReceived);
    }

    private void NotificationMessageReceived(NotificationMessage<Hotel> selectedHotel) {
        this.SelectedHotel = selectedHotel.Content;
    }
```

from the other viewModel, I send a message with the SelectedHotel.

```
private Hotel _selectedHotel { get; set; }
    public Hotel SelectedHotel {
        get { return _selectedHotel; }
        set {
            _selectedHotel = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedHotel");
            Messenger.Default.Send(new NotificationMessage<Hotel>(this, SelectedHotel, "SelectedHotel"));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `ItemsViewModel` you do not need the `OnSelecetedItemChanged` handler code at all. Instead, in the `MainWindowViewModel` store a reference to the `ItemsViewModel`, and add a handler there:

```
var ItemsViewModel = itemsVM = new ItemsViewModel();
itemsVm.PropertyChanged += SelectedHotelChanged;

// and then implement the handler:

public void SelectedHotelChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs args)
{
     SelectedHotel = itemsVM.SelectedHotel;  
}

// ensuring that the SelectedHotel property in the MainWindowViewModel also notifies when it changes.
```

Edit: Fixed a typo.

Comment: There isn't any handler OnPropertyChanged on ItemsViewModel

Comment: @StrouMfios: Yeah, sorry, working from memory :/ It's PropertyChanged, which comes from INotifyPropertyChanged (which your ViewModels should be implementing).

Comment: I have done your suggestion, in the constructor of mainWindowViewModel.  The selected property in mainWIndowViewModel have this RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedHotel"); but it doesn't notifies.