# TabControl - Share Main ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I want to be able to share controls between my main window and tab controls. Right now, I have a tab control and status bar on the main window. Status bar contains a button and progress bar. I want to share the progress bar. When the button is clicked, it resets progress bar.

The tabs contain a button. When clicked, it should increase the progress bar by 1.

What I've done: after digging through SO/other all day, I was able to set this up.

- MainWindowView
- -> Declares instance of MainWindowViewModel in xaml
- -> Declares tabs as usercontrols in xaml b/c will always have the same tabs
- TabControl1View
- -> Declares instance of TabControl2ViewModel in xaml

I need advice on how to talk to MainWindowViewModel in TabControl1View.

```
<Window x:Class="TabControlTest.MainWindowView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TabControlTest"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:MainWindowViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
<DockPanel>
    <StatusBar DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">
        <StatusBarItem HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" DockPanel.Dock="Top">
            <Button Height="25" Content="Reset" Command="{Binding MainWindowViewModel_ButtonClickCommand}"/>
        </StatusBarItem>
        <StatusBarItem HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">
            <ProgressBar Height="25" Maximum="10" Value="{Binding MainWindowViewModel_Progress, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        </StatusBarItem>
    </StatusBar>
    <TabControl>
        <TabItem>
            <local:TabControl1View/>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
</DockPanel>
```

```
class MainWindowViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    int progress = 0;

    public int MainWindowViewModel_Progress
    {
        get
        {
            return progress;
        }
        set
        {
            SetAndNotify(ref this.progress, value, () => this.MainWindowViewModel_Progress);
        }
    }

    ICommand _ButtonClickCommand;

    public ICommand MainWindowViewModel_ButtonClickCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return _ButtonClickCommand ?? (_ButtonClickCommand = new CommandHandler(() => MainWindowViewModel_ButtonClick(), true));
        }
    }

    public void MainWindowViewModel_ButtonClick()
    {
        MainWindowViewModel_Progress = 0; // Reset progress
    }
}
```

x

```
<UserControl x:Class="TabControlTest.TabControl1View"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TabControlTest"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <local:TabControl1ViewModel/>
</UserControl.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <Button Content="UP" Command="{Binding TabControl1ViewModel_UpClickCommand}"/>
</Grid>
```

```
class TabControl1ViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    ICommand _UpClickCommand;

    public ICommand TabControl1ViewModel_UpClickCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return _UpClickCommand ?? (_UpClickCommand = new CommandHandler(() => TabControl1ViewModel_UpClick(), true));
        }
    }

    public void TabControl1ViewModel_UpClick()
    {
        // I want to increase the progress bar here
    }
}
```

I found a good answer on using a mediator pattern here:
[How can I update a property of mainWindowViewModel from another ViewModel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4967913/how-can-i-update-a-property-of-mainwindowviewmodel-from-another-viewmodel)

But I don't understand how I can store a reference to TabControl1ViewModel in MainWindowViewModel.

Also found a ton of articles saying to declare the ViewModels inside MainViewModel and keep track of them, but they were always code snippets.

**Question: how do I pass MainViewModel.Progress to TabControlViewModel?**

I'm now going down the path of trying to put something like this in my MainViewModel

MainViewModel.ProgressChanged = TabControlView.(get TabControlViewModel).ProgressChanged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do this

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:MainWindowViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
```

or

```
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <local:TabControl1ViewModel/>
</UserControl.DataContext>
```

You are letting the View to create a instance of `MainWindowViewModel` or `TabControl1ViewModel` by itself and bind it to your View's datacontext. That makes you loose control of passing any constructor parameter to the control.

In your `MainWindowViewModel`'s constructor initialize the User control's Datacontext like

```
class MainWindowViewModel
{
    MainWindowViewModel
    {
     ChildViewModel  = new TabControl1ViewModel(this);
    }
    public TabControl1ViewModel ChildViewModel {get; private set;}
}

class TabControl1ViewModel
{
    public MainWindowViewModel ParentViewModel {get; private set;}
    TabControl1ViewModel(MainWindowViewModel mainWindowViewModel)
    {
        ParentViewModel  = mainWindowViewModel;
    }
}
```

View.Xaml

```
<Window x:Class="TabControlTest.MainWindowView"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TabControlTest"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:MainWindowViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
<DockPanel>
  .
  .
  .
   <TabControl>
        <TabItem>
            <local:TabControl1View DataContext={Binding ChildViewModel}/>
        </TabItem>
   </TabControl>
</DockPanel>
```

Comment: Thanks! Been stuck on that all day.